# Windows Task Scheduler to run Python Scripts

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, windows-task-scheduler

I am using VS Code to execute a python code. I want to automate this windows task scheduler,
however i am getting an error.

from VSCode this is what I see on terminal when I run the script;

```
Loading personal and system profiles took 712ms
(base) PS C:\Users\tableauautomation\Desktop\Python>  & 'C:\Users\tableauautomation\Anaconda3\python.exe' 'c:\Users\tableauautomation\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2020.7.96456\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\launcher' '64388' '--' 'c:\Users\tableauautomation\Desktop\Python\ForecastAutomation.py'
job Started: 2020-07-26 18:13:30
```

i am creating this in Notepad saved as bat but keep getting errors like Numpy or Panda's is not installed.

batchfile has this;
call activate my_env
"c:\Users\tableauautomation\Desktop\Python\ForecastAutomation.py"
pause

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write the below lines in your notepad with `.bat` format.

```
call activate [my_env]
python c:\Users\tableauautomation\Desktop\Python\ForecastAutomation.py
call conda deactivate
```

if absolute path of python is not included in `$PATH` then use absoulte path of python.exe in `.bat` file.

```
call activate [my_env]
c:\Users\tableauautomation\Anaconda3\python.exe c:\Users\tableauautomation\Desktop\Python\ForecastAutomation.py
call conda deactivate
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyone else have this issue the solution is here;
The batchfile needs the following parameter (Windows Machine)

cmd /c C:\Users\tableauautomation\Anaconda3\condabin\conda.bat run "C:\Users\tableauautomation\Anaconda3\python.exe" "c:\Users\tableauautomation\Desktop\Python\ForecastAutomation.py"
pause